# Python generator, non-swallowing exception in 'coroutine'

Tags: python, exception, generator

I recently came across some surprising behaviour in Python generators:

```
class YieldOne:
  def __iter__(self):
    try:
      yield 1
    except:
      print '*Excepted Successfully*'
      # raise

for i in YieldOne():
  raise Exception('test exception')
```

Which gives the output:

```
*Excepted Successfully*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
Exception: test exception
```

I was (pleasantly) surprised that `*Excepted Successfully*` got printed, as this was what I wanted, but also surprised that the Exception still got propagated up to the top level.  I was expecting to have to use the (commented in this example) `raise` keyword to get the observed behaviour.

Can anyone explain why this functionality works as it does, and why the `except` in the generator doesn't swallow the exception?

Is this the only instance in Python where an `except` doesn't swallow an exception?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code does not do what you think it does. You cannot raise Exceptions in a coroutine like this. What you do instead is catching the [`GeneratorExit`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.GeneratorExit) exception. See what happens when you use a different Exception:

```
class YieldOne:
  def __iter__(self):
    try:
      yield 1
    except RuntimeError:
        print "you won't see this"
    except GeneratorExit:
      print 'this is what you saw before'
      # raise

for i in YieldOne():
  raise RuntimeError
```

As this still gets upvotes, here is how you raise an Exception in a generator:

```
class YieldOne:
  def __iter__(self):
    try:
      yield 1
    except Exception as e:
      print "Got a", repr(e)
      yield 2
      # raise

gen = iter(YieldOne())

for row in gen:
    print row # we are at `yield 1`
    print gen.throw(Exception) # throw there and go to `yield 2`
```

See docs for [`generator.throw`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator.throw).

Comment: Aha, now it makes sense. I didn't originally expect the exception to propogate 'over' to the generator.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: What THC4k said.

If you really want to raise an arbitrary exception inside a generator, use the `throw` method:

```
>>> def Gen():
...     try:
...             yield 1
...     except Exception:
...             print "Excepted."
...
>>> foo = Gen()
>>> next(foo)
1
>>> foo.throw(Exception())
Excepted.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

You'll notice that you get a `StopIteration` at the top level. These are raised by generators which have run out of elements; they are usually swallowed by the `for` loop but in this case we made the generator raise an exception so the loop doesn't notice them.